# Can't find a proper unitary operator $L^2[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to L^2[0,+\infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis

It seems that I can't find a proper translation, does anybody have an idea?
It seems that every integral that I try to calculate diverges.

I also tried to see any of the classic examples such as rotations can help, but it seems that this gets me nowhere: https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unitary_operator
Aany help will be appriciated,
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

$Tf(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt {1+x^{2}}} f(\arctan x)$ is such a map.

Answer (score 0):

You can map $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,\pi/2)$ by arctan as suggested above, or by any number of changes of variables, such as
$$
                   \varphi(y)=\frac{1}{2/\pi+y}
$$
$$
    \int_0^{\pi/2}|f(x)|^2dx=-\int_0^{\infty}|f\circ\varphi(y)|^2\varphi'(y)dy
  = \int_0^{\infty}|f\circ\varphi(y)|^2\frac{1}{(2/\pi+y)^2}dy
$$
Then,
$$
                 (Lf)(y) = \frac{1}{2/\pi+y}f\circ\varphi(y)
$$
is a unitary map from $L^2[0,\pi/2]$ to $L^2[0,\infty)$.